# how to make scriptom work with soapUI

Tags: soapui, scriptom

I want to use scriptom to access COM objects in soapUI but i am not able to get beyond step 1, i.e., installing scriptom.

I have tried the steps mentioned in http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=96 but when i run a simple command(see below)

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*
def tdc = new ActiveXObject ('TDApiOle80.TDConnection')
```

i get a class not defined error(see below)
[image]

Has anyone been able to successfully use scriptom with soapUI? If yes can you please help me?

ps: i am using soapUI 4.5.2 Pro and OS. I need scriptom to work with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work by following these steps

1. Install groovy or download the latest groovy binary
2. find out the java.library.path in soapUI using

   log.info System.properties["java.library.path"]
3. copy the scriptom jar files in the soapui_HOME/bin/ext folder
4. copy the jacob*.jar file in soapui_home/bin/ext folder
5. copy the jacob*.dll (both) into the java.library.path location from step 2. This is usually the soapUI_home/bin folder
6. restart soapUI and verify that you can see messages in the soapUI log that the jars were loaded.
7. run a simple scriptom code to verify that the setup worked. I used the below code.

   import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*

   // instantiate Internet Explorer
   def explorer = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   // set its properties
   explorer.Visible = true
   explorer.AddressBar = true

   // navigate to a site by calling the Navigate() method
   explorer.Navigate("http://abhishekasthana.com")

And that's it...