# Get multiple responses from a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I'm using SoapUI to use a web service in my job but the problem is that i need to validate a lot of user's code and SoapUI just let me get the client info one client at a time. I need to know if there is a way to consume the Web Service with multiple code clients.

Example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/" xmlns:san="http://platform.enterprise/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <san:checkClientAddress>
         <id>000098732</id>
      </san:checkClientAddress>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I need to get the result from 500 clients but if i use SoapUI I have to get response from one client at a time.

Comment: could you please share some code with us.

Comment: Depending on the service it may not be faster to call it with multiple threads or, in the worst case, it might blacklist you for trying to DOS attack it. If the WSDL does not specify a way to query multiple items then you are probably just going to have to wait.

Comment: Do you want to perform calls one-by-one with different credentials or perform several calls concurrently?

Comment: I want to perform calls one by one and get the response of the ws

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write your own data driven script like described here [SOAP UI data driven testing for web requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681273/soap-ui-data-driven-testing-for-web-requests) or refer to JMeter and use optian called 'CSV Data Set Config'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test suite in SoapUI with multiple test steps, one call for each value you want to sent to the web service. Check out http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/functional-testing.html and other similar pages for how to get started.

If you're using SoapUI pro, you can use a data source as described in the video to quickly test with a lot of different input rather than having to create individual test steps for each input.