# Imported jars not working on SoapUI

Tags: groovy, jar, soapui

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724929/how-to-make-scriptom-work-with-soapui/) as a reference i was trying to import some jars to SoapUI.

I follow all the required steps to do it:

**/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin**
[image]

**/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext**
[image]

**SoapUI console**
[image]

But im getting an error when i try to import a class:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject;
```

> ERROR:An error occurred [startup failed:
>   Script1.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject
>    @ line 10, column 1.

I appreciate any help or suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add your script which is causing the error?

Comment: Already edited @Rao

Comment: You already pointed the solution, does not it help?

Comment: Im getting the error even after i import the jars, so i still got the problem.

Comment: Please check the instructions and see if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make scriptom work with soapUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724929/how-to-make-scriptom-work-with-soapui)

Comment: @SiKing i used that answer as a guide to import them but im still getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: Post your differences from that answer.

Comment: In your `bin/ext` you show only scriptom*sources.jar. Where are your scriptom.jar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following instructions.

Close soapui, if it is already running, before proceeding. Also revert the changes you made previously, i.e., remove library you placed in different locations of `SOAPUI_HOME` just to make it clean and isolate.

1. Download `scriptom-1.6.0` library from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/scriptom/scriptom-1.6.0.jar.zip)
2. Extract `scriptom-1.6.0.jar` from above download zip to `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory.
3. Download `jacob` library from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/files/jacob-project/1.18/jacob-1.18.zip)
4. Extract `jacob-1.18-x64.dll` (if 64 bit machine) or `jacob-1.18-x86.dll` (if x86 machine) from `jacob-1.18.zip` file to `SOAPUI_HOME/bin` directory.
5. Extract `jacob.jar` from `jacob-1.18.zip` file to `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory.

*Start your soapui.*

Try running your script.